# How do I relate two datepickerdialogs on Android Studio/java?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have two buttons for check in and check out.And I am using datepickerdialog to set dates.When I set the date of check in,the date of check out must be future dates not past dates.I mean I want to set dates to related each other.

```
    private void setDateGiris(){
        datePickerDialog =new DatePickerDialog(context, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                girisDate.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
                entryC = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                entry = entryC.getTime();

            }
        },current_year,current_month,current_day);

        calender.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
      datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,getString(R.string.pick),datePickerDialog);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
    private void setDateCikis(){

        datePickerDialog =new DatePickerDialog(context, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                cikisDate.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
//                exitC = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);
//                exit = exitC.getTime();
            }
        },entry.getYear(),entry.getMonth(),entry.getDay()+1);

        calender.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);

        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
       datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,getString(R.string.pick),datePickerDialog);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```